# What's namespace in JavaScript and how to export method from namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, namespaces, single-page-application

**[Please check this link for my complete code (It's simple though)](http://jsfiddle.net/js9zty07/)**

Question 1: What's the namespace defined in JavaScript? From my understanding, it looks like that any object can be an namespace?

Say we have a namespace called 'SPA', which means "Simple Page Application", inside this namespace, I define four module scope variables, $chatSlider, $toggleSlider, $onclickSlider, initModule;

```
var spa = (function( $ ) {
    // Module scope variables
    var
    // Set constants
        configMap = {
            // some code here
        },

        // Declare all other module scope variables
        $chatSlider, toggleSlider, onClickSlider, initModule;

    toggleSlider = function() {
        // some code here
        }
        // do not take action if slider is in transition
        return false;
    }

    onClickSlider = function(event) {
        toggleSlider();
        return false;
    }

    // Public method / initModule/ 
    // sets initial state and provides feature

    initModule = function($container) {
       // some code here
        return true;
    };

    return {
        initModule: initModule
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And now I want to call initModule outside "spa", like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    spa.initModule( $('#spa'));
});
```

Question 2: why we have to write

```
return {
    initModule: initModule
};
```

To me, return {initModule} seems make more sense, what does the code above mean, what's the syntax of it?

Last but not least, usually I write function in the format like

```
function ( $var) {
   // function code here
}
```

So what does this $ and jQuery mean here

```
function( $ ) {

}(jQuery)
```

Comment: *"To me, return {initModule} seems make more sense"* You might be happy to hear that ES6 will introduce short object notation, where `{initModule}` is equivalent to `{initModule: initModule}`.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the namespace defined in JavaScript?

Namespace isn't a piece of terminology defined by the language. It's common usage just means "An object, assigned to a global variable, to which all public functions for a piece of code are assigned so they can be exposed globally while only using a single global variable".

> why we have to write `return {` etc etc

Otherwise the immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) will return `undefined`. The return value is what is assigned to the global variable (`spa`).

You need it to be an object.

The left hand side of the `:` is the property name, the right hand side is the value (which is the previously declared local variable which happens to have the same name as the property).

> `return {initModule}` seems make more sense

That's a syntax error in JavaScript. An object consists of a set of property/value *pairs*.

> So what does this $ and jQuery mean here

`$` is the name of the argument in the function expression definition.

`jQuery` is the value passed as the first argument when that function is called (which is immediately).

Comment: Do I have to define a IIFE here? What's the point of making the var spa = function ($) {} () a IIFE? What if I don't add the () behind?

Comment: The design pattern depends on it. If you don't call the function, then you assign the function to the variable instead of its return value.

Comment: This is called the Revealing Module pattern.  You can learn more about it AND other patterns at http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/